# exchange gpu data from python (pycuda gpuarray) to opencv (cv::cuda::GpuMat) and vice versa

Tags: python, opencv, pycuda

I have a pycuda gpuarray that I would like to feed to an opencv cuda function. As I understand there are currently no python bindings for the opencv 3 cv::cuda module. So I tried writing my own python wrapper for accessing cv::cuda functions (in my case cv::cuda::HOG class).

Unfortunately I hit a road block when it comes to the central part of data exchange. I know that you can use a structure like

```
static PyObject* my_function(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
  int test;
  PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "t", &test);
}
```

To pass elementary data types, but I do not know how to do that with pointers on gpu memory (in my case `gpuarray.gpudata`). My understanding is that `gpuarray.gpudata` yields a pointer according to the `dtype` of the `gpuarray` but on the gpu.

So on the python side things would look like this:

```
input_gpu = gpuarray.zeros(shape=(3,3), dtype=numpy.float32)
output_gpu = gpuarray.zeros(shape=(3,3), dtype=numpy.float32)
my_function(input.gpudata, output.gpudata)
```

On C++ side I would have to use `cv:cuda::GpuMat`, so how to I get from `gpuarray.gpudata` to `cv:cuda::GpuMat` and vice versa?

Comment: Good question, I'm also trying to combine opencv.cuda with pycuda. How did you solve the problem?